# ios parse framework query on user

Tags: ios, swift, parse-framework

I am trying to fetch some objects from the USER table in parse.
I am absolutely sure that the username I am searching for is there but I even though I get a `objects!.count == 0` when I do this:

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "User") as PFQuery
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: "myUsername")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if objects!.count > 0{
                println("there are some objects like this!")
            } else {
                println("There are no objects like this!")
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
```

I have been trying the same with `objectId` but no luck I seriously don't know what to do with it .. it seems like something very easy.

Comment: There is a user called `"myUsername"` or did you just forget to remove the trailing and leading `"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When querying for a user you can't use

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "User") as PFQuery
```

because the `User` class has a special name. Instead you need to use:

```
let query = PFUser.query()
```

Comment: Unbelievable! Thank you very much. I spent like 2 days figuring out what's going on.